# Response body null when call succeeded (android)

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, retrofit2

Please help. I invoke method on server from android and i got success with null response body. My server is ASP.NET Web API, on android client I use retrofit2.

Method on the server (route is "Players/IsParticipant/"):

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("IsParticipant"), HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult IsParticipant(int meetingId, string username)
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }
```

And in android:

```
@GET("players/isParticipant")
Call<Boolean> isParticipant(@Query("username") String username, @Query("meetingId") int meetingId);
```

When I invoke it:

```
Call<Boolean> call = service.isParticipant("aa", 1);
    call.enqueue(new CustomCallback<Boolean>(this)
    {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Boolean model)
        {
            DialogUtils.Show(getApplicationContext(), model.toString());
        }
    });
```

I got an error because model is null. Why? How am I supposed to fix it? I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: its the same result when i use (default) Callback

Comment: Try using JsonObject instead of Boolean in Call<Boolean> and put a break point on DialogUtils.Show(getApplicationContext(), model.toString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following sample code:

ASP.NET Web API:

```
[Route("api/values/getbool/{id:int}/{username}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetBool(int id, string username)
{
    return Ok(true);
}
```

Android:

build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.0.2'
    ...
}
```

WebAPIService.java:

```
public interface WebAPIService {
    ...
    @GET("/api/values/getbool/{id}/{username}")
    Call<Boolean> getBool(@Path("id") int id, @Path("username") String username);
    ...
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
...
Retrofit retrofit1 = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API_URL_BASE)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
WebAPIService service1 = retrofit1.create(WebAPIService.class);

Call<Boolean> booleanCall = service1.getBool(1, "user");
booleanCall.enqueue(new Callback<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Boolean> call, Response<Boolean> response) {
        Log.i("onResponse", String.valueOf(response.body()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Boolean> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("onFailure", t.toString());
    }
});
...
```

Logcat result:

```
05-05 14:10:30.291 15755-15755/com.example.asyncretrofit I/onResponse: true
```